# R - Plot 2-way Anova Results on longitudinal data using GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am looking to display the results of a two-way Anova analysis over several time points. This is preliminary data, and I am interested in getting an understanding of the potential relationship between time and sex on tumor burden.

My data:

```
    ID  Sex Tumor.Burden    Time.Point
Cage3   female  1270800 1
Cage3   female  1237600 2
Cage3   female  1288760 3
Cage3   female  775220  4
Cage4   female  1768400 1
Cage4   female  1630200 2
Cage4   female  1606900 3
Cage4   female  1134220 4
Cage5   male    1441500 1
Cage5   male    3000750 2
Cage5   male    5930500 3
Cage5   male    6944225 4
Cage6   male    2063640 1
Cage6   male    7067600 2
Cage6   male    10460400 3
Cage6   male    18764800 4
```

This is the plot I am using. I'd like to point out that this wasn't made with the data I just listed, but rather with similar data. However, I plan on using the same approach here.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time.Point, y = Tumor.Burden, color = Sex)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal()  +
  labs(title = "Weekly Follow-up of Tumor-Bearing Mice", x = "Time points (weeks)", y="Log(Tumor Burden)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: Longitudinal Data]

What is the best approach to add the significance of each time point above to the corresponding time point on the plot? I.E is there a statistically significant difference between males and females at time point 1:5?

Currently, I am following this: https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/repeated-measures-anova-in-r/#two-way-repeated-measures-anova. However, I am getting an error at the end and it seems to be related to my ID variable getting flagged as NA when I run

```
Data %>%
  group_by(Time.Point) %>%
   anova_test(dv = Tumor.Burden, wid = ID, within = Sex)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the p values you can use `anova_test(Tumor.Burden ~ Sex)` and use these output p values in a `geom_text` to show them in your plot like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)

p_values <- Data %>%
  group_by(Time.Point) %>%
  anova_test(Tumor.Burden ~ Sex)
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
p_values
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   Time.Point Effect   DFn   DFd     F     p `p<.05`   ges
#> *      <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1          1 Sex        1     2 0.342 0.618 ""      0.146
#> 2          2 Sex        1     2 3.11  0.22  ""      0.608
#> 3          3 Sex        1     2 8.83  0.097 ""      0.815
#> 4          4 Sex        1     2 4.05  0.182 ""      0.669

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(Data, mapping = aes(x = Time.Point, y = Tumor.Burden, color = Sex)) + 
  geom_text(data = p_values, mapping = aes(x = Time.Point, y = 15000000, label = p), size = 3) +
  theme_minimal()  +
  labs(title = "Weekly Follow-up of Tumor-Bearing Mice", x = "Time points (weeks)", y="Log(Tumor Burden)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Quinten! Ethical question, to get rid of the vertical lines I merged the groups of males together and the group of females together. This produces a line plot like the one previewed in my post. I then overlay these values to the other plot. As long as I specify this to my audience (my lab) and I tell them that the reason was strictly for aesthetics, I don't think it is a huge concern. Thoughts?